# prove that the equation has root when x>0

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, continuity, roots, absolute-value

**prove that $\left\lvert{x-a_1}\right\rvert$+$\ldots$+$\left\lvert{x-a_i}\right\rvert$=$\frac{n}{2}$has root when x>0**

> **given that ${a_1}$+$\ldots$+${a_i}$=1   , $i=1\ldots n$, and $0\leq a_i\leq1$**
> I tried finding $$\sum_{i=0}^n{\left\lvert{x-a_i}\right\rvert}$$
> I found $$\sum_{i=0}^n{x}=nx$$ and $$\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i}=1$$
> so $$\sum_{i=0}^n{\left\lvert{x-a_i}\right\rvert}=|nx-1|$$
> I made assisted function $$f(x)=|nx-1|-\frac{n}{2}$$
> and I tried to prove that the equation has root when x>0 with the intermediate value theorem
> but I don't know how to remove **"n"** from the equation so i can determent if the final result when assigning  x value is negative or positive

Comment: Please clean up the post. Too many typos in math.

Comment: You might try plotting the $\sum_i |x-a_i|$ for the example $n = 2$, $a_1 = 1/3$, $a_2 = 2/3$ to get some insight into why $\sum_i |x -a_i|$ cannot be $|xn-1|$ (which only has one local minimum in $x$).

Comment: Can you find some values of $x$ such that $f(x_1) = \sum_i |x - a_i| < \frac n2$ and $f(x_2) > \frac n2$? What to do next?

Comment: Are your sums involving $a_i$ or only $a_1$?

Comment: Two typos in particular ! $a_1+\cdots +a_i=1$ for all $i$  ? It is impossible unless $a_1=1$ and all $a_i=0$ for $i>1$...

Comment: $a_i$ can be a rational number  its not just  a full integer so it can be 0.1+0.6+0.3=1

Comment: Consider 1) $a_i > 0.5 \; \forall i$ 2) $a_i < 0.5 \; \forall i$ and 3) some over 0.5 some under

Comment: @karam Does your first equation involves any $a_i$ for $i\ne 1$?

Comment: @Andrei $i=1\ldots n$ for every  $a_i$ $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$

Comment: @karam In the first equation (and in other places as well) all the terms are $x-a_1$, not $x-a_i$ (number 1 versus letter i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Define $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n|x-a_i|$.

What happens with $f(x)$ for $x \to \infty$? What is the sign of the terms inside the absolute value function? What happens with $x\to 0$? Try other values. If you find a function value below $n/2$ you are done  because the function is continuous (see intermediate value theorem).